# Can a raycast 'see' an instanced object?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, instances

The problem I'm running into is I need my Raycast to 'hit' the instanced objects. I am unsure how to get that to happen.

What I'm noticing is that it is able to hit the original object in the collection. Just not any of the instances.

I don't really know what I need to fix to make it work. Attaching some images that hopefully explain the issue better than I can.

[image]

[image: What's not working.]

[image: The collections]

[image: The geometry node for the laser pointer.]

[image: The part I think needs a fix to make it work, but I don't know what to change.]

[image: Unsure if the instancing panel has anything to do with it not working.]

Comment: Could you please provide a blend file on https://blend-exchange.com/ and link it right here. This makes it easier to help you. Besides, your node setup has a low resolution and thus is difficult to read.

Comment: Edited the post with the .blend

Comment: no, it can't. You have to do "object -> make instances real" to make it work

Comment: Well, that's at least better than what I had, thank you!